# Share a database connection pool between sequelize and pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a server which I've written using Express and [node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) (pg). It creates its own DB pool:

```
const dbPool = new pg.Pool(dbConfig);
```

and runs SQL queries directly using this connection.

Now I'm adding a new table and corresponding REST API. I'd like to use [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) and [epilogue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/epilogue) to reduce the boilerplate. Unfortunately, sequelize wants to create its own database connection pool:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, config);
```

Is it possible to re-use the existing connection pool or otherwise share it between my existing `pg` code and my new `sequelize` code?

Comment: Why do you want two different database frameworks for the same connection?

Comment: @vitaly-t because I'd like to use sequelize for some new features without having to migrate all my existing node-postgres code. The current solution is to just have two connections. That's fine, I just wanted to check if there was a sanctioned way to have a single connection.

Comment: Those are two independent pools, with different protocols and underlying objects. So unless you are willing to hack the two libraries, the answer would be NO, you cannot do it as it is.

Comment: I would like this for the opposite reason: I have existing code in Sequelize, but want to use a feature of pg.Pool that isn't available through Sequelize.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize does not offer the option to pass a custom pool, but you can pass options that will get used to create the sequelize pool, such as min and max connections.

What I would do in your case is to check your total DB connection count, and make a repartition based on the expected usage of your two pools.

For example if you have 20 connections max on your database:

```
const dbPool = new pg.Pool({
  max: 10
});

const sequelize = new Sequelize(/* ... */, {
  // ...
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});
```

I would also suggest using environment variables to set the max connection on your sequelize pool and nod-pg pool, so that you could adapt easily your repartition if needed.